# Get viewport height excluding non-visible content

Tags: jquery, viewport

I'm getting the `$(window).height()`, but when the page is in portrait, and the page is scrollable about 5 pages down I get that total height, instead of the visible 'viewport'.

What I want is to get the ratio of the page height/width. So when landscape is 1600 by 900, i get a ratio of (1600/900) 1.8.

When it's in landscape I get something like 400 width, 2400 height, then the ratio is 5, that's not wat I want.

I tried several methods mentioned here: http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/, but none actually give me the actual visible viewport, instead it will give me the height of the content.

I only tested it in FF for now..

*Update:*

It seems to only happen in portrait mode, and only when bootstrap.js considers the size of the viewport to be 'phone' sized, I can't resize my chrome window to that size (only 'tablet' size), so I don't know if Chrome has the same issue.

Comment: It sure doesn't work that way for me. The Stackoverflow front page is quite long, but calling `$(window).height()` on it gives the correct screen size (well, somewhat smaller than the screen size due to browser chrome etc).

Comment: Yeah, I remember it working like that, it could have something to do with bootstrap.js, I'm using the row-fluid class, so that in landscape it's next to eachother, and in portrait, it is stacked..